# It maybe inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to code a download manager but get this error:
'save' is not declared. It maybe inaccessible due to its protection level

Here is my code:

```
    Imports System.Net
    Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents httpclient As webClient

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Try
            httpclient = New WebClient
            Dim total As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
            Dim current As Integer = -1
            While current < total
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex = current + 1
                Dim download As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
                httpclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(download), save)
                Label3.Text = "Current Status: Downloading:..."
                Do While httpclient.IsBusy
                    Application.DoEvents()
                Loop
                current = current + 1
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what does `save` refer to in your code

Comment: The second parameter of DownloadFileAsync is a string with the name of the file. Where do you have declared the variable `save`? Did you have [Option Explicit ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) ?

Comment: I was originally following a tutorial online and ran into this problem. http://youtu.be/-k1erkfOKjY?t=7m56s

Comment: Where is the variable `save` declared?

Answer (score 1):

`DownloadFileAsync` takes 2 parameters. The first is the URL of the file to download and the second is the local location to save the file.  The tutorial you were following likely set the variable `Save` somewhere in the code.

To get this to work, you can replace it with something like  `"C:\Test.txt"` to download it to that location or define the variable `Save` and set it's value to the location you want to save the file.

With your existing code, to allow a user to select the save location, you need to make the following changes. Declare the `Save` variable private to the form, under the `Public Class Form1` line:

```
Private Save as string
```

Then in your `Button1_Click` event, it should look more like this:

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Save = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
End If
```

Comment: How would I allow the user to choose the download location?

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim download As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
            httpclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(download), "save")
```